# Set action dynamically in Charge subscription form

Tags: charge

When using Charge to handle subscriptions is it possible to set the Charge Action (not the HTML form action parameter) dynamically based on which subscription option has been chosen in the form?

For instance, I have 3 different subscriptions available. 
Depending which subscription is chosen the member is to be put into a different member group. This was to be done using Charge's Actions.

But it appears that you must set the Action as a parameter on {exp:charge:form}.

Is it possible to set the Action dynamically within the form?

Comment: did you manage to do anything with this? I've got the same situation. I've now opted for a list of subscriptions and passing action data via the next but the above would be better.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8521)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can set the on_success parameter of the exp:charge:form tag based on a url segment. Then, you can create different Actions assigning different Subscriptions based on your needs.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: I'm just seeing now that you're looking for something different here. I think I provided a solution similar to JonnyT. Sorry about that!